# Sparx Enterprise Architect EA 15 - how to include a decision table in a report

Tags: report, enterprise-architect

While modelling business processes within Enterprise Architect, I would like to publish a (Word/RTF) report of the modelled processes which also includes the decision element that can be definied for any element (see screenshot). Whenever I generate a report, the table is not exported, and I do not find a corresponding element.

How can this be done in EA 15?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't, or at least not easily.

The decision tree data is stored in `t_document.bincontent`, but it is not easily accessible from the API.

In order to get the info into an RTF document you would need to

- make a script fragment
- write a script to

  - get the `t_document.bincontent` data
  - decode the binary data. EA sometimes uses a base64 encoded zipped file. If that is the case with this bincontent then you have to base64 decode the data, save it as a .zip file, unzip it and get the data from the text file that was unzipped.
  - interpret the data in the text file
  - return the xml string as required by the script fragment.
- call the script in your script fragment

All of this is not for the faint-hearted, with no guarantee for success.